# Augmented Reality with Ionic Framework

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, augmented-reality, wikitude

I would like to ask if someone has tryed to use Ionic Framework with AR, like Wikitude or ezAR?
I'm new in this specific field and I don't know how to start.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Wikitude has a very good documentation and yes, i already developed an application with wikitude and ionic but like i said, i would recommend you to start with the docs and get deeper into the whole topic.

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate it....if you want to help me with this project you are welcome :-)

Comment: If you'd like to, you can send me an e-mail to support@cordova.de. Greetings from germany.

Answer (score 4):

Anything works with cordova should also work with the Ionic Framework, then wikitude is a good choice. And they have some good samples: [wikitude-sdk-example-git](https://github.com/Wikitude/wikitude-sdk-samples)